# Grails Domain Class Events

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am new to Grails and I am curious about domain class hooks like `beforeinsert()`, `beforeupdate()`, ... etc.
But I can't find a good resource/documentation on how to use this feature.

Can someone give me a good resource or explain to me how this things work?

Comment: actually the grails gorm documention here: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping  is very clear but I have created state chart diagram and put the definitions here for quick access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods are a way of hooking into the domain instance lifecylce.

The [grails gorm documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping) is very clean and precise so I will quote the definitions from there but I created a state chart diagram to depict the picture:

[image]

> - beforeInsert - Executed before an object is initially persisted to    the database. If you return false, the insert will be cancelled.
> - beforeUpdate - Executed before an object is updated. If you return    false, the update will be cancelled.
> - beforeDelete - Executed before an object is deleted. If you return    false, the delete will be cancelled.
> - beforeValidate - Executed before an object is validated
> - afterInsert - Executed after an object is persisted to the database
> - afterUpdate - Executed after an object has been updated
> - afterDelete - Executed after an object has been deleted
> - onLoad - Executed when an object is loaded from the database